# How to increment QLineEdit name to access value?

Tags: python, variables, pyqt, increment, qlineedit

This seems like a really simple question, but has me stumped.  I've got a UI that has multiple QLineEdits for names, start, and end times.  For example:

clipName1, clipStart1, clipEnd1
clipName2, clipStart2, clipEnd2
clipName2, clipStart3, clipEnd3

These are not dynamically built on the fly.  They are static.  I wish to access the values from these by going through a loop.  I am not sure how I can append an integer onto the variable name and still be able to access the value.  I've tried this which I know doesn't work:

```
    clipTotal = 4

    for i in range(1, clipTotal+1):
        clipName = self.clipName+str(i)+.text()
```

Comment: `clipName = getattr(self, 'clipName%d' % i).text()`

Comment: THANK YOU!  I am not sure what this function is for, but it works.  I will need to look it up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by ekhumoro in comments above:

clipName = getattr(self, 'clipName%d' % i).text()